# cakephp app error problem

Tags: cakephp

I have the following function in my app_controller:

```
function beforeFilter() {
    $this->set('lastThreePosts', $this->Blog->find_latest_posts());
}
```

I then use the variable 'lastThreePosts' that I have set in my layout. This works fine apart from on my 404 page where I get the following error:

```
Notice (8): Undefined index: lastThreePosts [APP\views\layouts\default.ctp, line 29]
```

I have made my own 404 page by created the file error404.ctp in my /views/errors/ directory.

So it seems when theres a 404 error the code in the controller doesn't get executed. Does anyone know how  I can make it work?

Thanks

Comment: Why are you doing that in the beforeFilter? While it isn't necessarily wrong, it isn't necessarily right either as you will be performing that query before every method called on that controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Phew! I found the answer here:

http://www.bradezone.com/2009/05/21/cakephp-beforefilter-and-the-error-error/